# When do environment strings not have "name=value" form?

Tags: linux, environment-variables

If I am correct, the environment of a process is an array of strings. The strings usually have the form "name=value", but not necessarily. I was wondering for what purposes the strings don't have the "name=value" form? Thanks.

Comment: Can you give such an example?

Comment: When your program calls `execve()` to execute a program, you can give whatever strings to the env argument. It is up to the program being invoked to interpret the environment strings. But I haven't seen such example.

Comment: Isn't `name=value` the shell's way of assigning values?  Seeing a counterexample would clarify what you're asking about.

Comment: I didn't mention shell. My post is asking for such cases and their purposes.

Comment: Is the commandline (and its parameters) not part of the environment of a program?  They sure can be in another format.

Comment: I had an example of another different case, but the question has been closed.

Comment: @JdeBP  Thanks. I'd appreciate reopen vote, and look forward to hearing your case either in comment or reply. Or you can add your case to my post, just separate it from my original post by a separator line.

Comment: I can't understand the close reason, this question perfectly clear to me. Reviewers: Please read the answer, then vote for reopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of anything actually using or expecting environment strings that don't contain `=`. Those would typically be pathological cases.

GNU `env` or `printenv` will faithfully print them.

For some languages, those strings will be out of reach. For instance, if you call `perl` with a `foo` env string, it won't show in `keys(%ENV)`, though `perl` would still pass it along to the commands it executes (unless you reset the whole `%ENV` hash).

So one could possibly use that to bypass some environment sanitizing (though proper environment sanitizing should start with an empty environment).

Some tools (like some shells) strip them from the environment they receive and don't pass them along to commands they execute, so in general it's not a good idea to rely on that.

Beside the `=`-less env strings, other pathological cases include env strings with duplicate variable name (like both `foo=good` and `foo=bad` passed in `envp`) which has already been seen as causing vulnerabilities (like [CVE-2016-2381](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=127158)), and env strings like `=foo` (empty variable name; note that POSIX `putenv()`/`getenv()` can set/get that variable, but not `setenv()`).